# jQuery inArray giving wrong result

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to check if "4" exists in an array so I'm using inArray. It keeps saying "It's not there" even though "4" is definitely there. Here's a chunk of it:

```
        var sp_20 = ["4"];

        function checkPrice(){

            if ( $.inArray("4", "sp_20") > -1 ) {
                alert("It's there");
            }
            else {
                alert("It's not there");
            }

        }
```

I borrowed the code from another answer here on the site, but it doesn't seem to work here!

Comment: yay a downvote already, any reason why?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the sp_20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified the array obj in wrong way.
Try following:

```
var sp_20 = ["4"];

        function checkPrice(){

            if ( $.inArray("4", sp_20) > -1 ) {
                alert("It's there");
            }
            else {
                alert("It's not there");
            }

        }
```

Or you can just simply use indexOf() function like

```
if(sp_20.indexOf("4") > -1) {
    alert("It's there");
} else {
    alert("It's not there");
}
```

With the variable:

```
var y = "5";
var sp_20 = ["1", y, "2"];

if (sp_20.indexOf(y) > -1) {
        alert("It's there");
} else {
        alert("It's NOT there");
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! If I wanted to replace the '4' with a variable, is there a special way to write that? I have a variable saved as 'y' but that seems to break it (using the indexOf method)

Comment: @ERushforth I have updated the post to show how to use variable in array and inside of the function. Btw, why dont you check my answer as accepted? :-)

Comment: Also works, thanks! I had to wait 10 minutes before it let me accept, sorry about that. I have a question about using a variable instead of sp_20 if you could possibly help me. Instead of 'sp' I was hoping to use something like (x + _20) so the x variable makes up the first 2 letters (in this example SP!) if that makes sense? I just cant glue the x to the _20 without it breaking!

Comment: Well, you can use eval() function. So eval(x + '_20') indicates sp_20 variable